# Confusion with how to make an augmented matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

You see a picture taken from a linear algebra book where a linear system of equations is presented in the equivalent augmented matrix form. I'm confused about the representation of the first equation in the augmented matrix. What happened to the constant 4? Shouldn't the first row in the matrix be [ 0 -1 -1 1 | -4 ]?

[image: pic]

Comment: yep, looks like an error

Answer (score 1):

I think its misprinting.

We don't have variable $x_1$ in first row. And we have to write coefficient of $x_1$. That is equal to zero.

But then on right hand side we have -4. So some type of mistake in question.

Comment: I understand the zero for the coefficient of $x_1$ but the 4 completely disappeared.

Comment: I edited my answer.